# How to do automated postgres database backups in google app engine for django app?

Tags: django, postgresql, cron, backup

I have a Django app running in standard Google App Engine, using postgres SQL.

I am using Google Cloud SQL (postgres) with Google App Engine. **How do I backup database everyday at 2am, and save the .sql file in Google Storage Bucket?**

I want to run a daily cron to save db snapshot in one of the buckets.

Using django-extensions and django-dbbackup, I have created a cron job, which works locally. But on GAE I get this error:

`dbbackup.db.exceptions.CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump db-development --host=67.74.73.21 --port=5432 --username=db-development-user --no-password --clean`

***How do I set the psql password or use .pgpass file in GAE?***

Code:

```
# cron.yaml
cron:
- description: "DB Backup CRON job"
  url: /core/cron-jobs  # the path to your view
  schedule: every 2 minutes  # the frequency for running the job
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 120
    max_doublings: 5
```

---

```
# views.py
def my_background_job(request):
    call_command('runjobs', 'daily')
    return HttpResponse('Cron run success', status="200")
```

---

```
# myapp>jobs>daily>db_backup.py (example documented in django_extensions)

from django_extensions.management.jobs import DailyJob

class Job(DailyJob):
    help = "Django Daily DB Backups"

    def execute(self):
        from django.core import management
        management.call_command("dbbackup")
```

---

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_extensions',
    'dbbackup',  # django-dbbackup
]
```

Postgres backup documention in https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/backing-up is vague. What Google terms as "automated backup", isnt much helpful for me, since I dont get the DB Dump in a *.psql file anywhere. They do mention "Currently, you can only use the API to set custom locations for backups." but its only for the geographic address.

How do I do **automated** daily backups of my postgres DB (as *.psql dump files in Google storage bucket) for my Django app running on google app engine?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the below link.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting

It describes how you can use the gcloud command or rest API to export your database in SQL dump or CSV format and save it to Cloud Storage.

Internally, it uses pg_dump, which is the same thing the django-dbbackup extension also uses.